# Unable to deploy guided action component to scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

While doing the initial push to a scratch org - RecordActionDeployment API (guided action) component is failing with error:

> Looks like this flow is inactive. Ask your Salesforce admin to
>   activate it.

The flows being referenced in the guided action are active so it should deploy them along with the guided action but not sure why it thinks those flows are inactive.

Has anyone come across this? So far I haven't found anything on this error anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunalty this is not possible at this time.
See also this know issue: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001lZn5QAE&title=deployment-of-a-flow-component-recordactiondeployment-component-together-fails

Only known workaround is to deploy first the flow and then the RecordActionDeployment metadata. (+ related metadata)